# C# The items inside the list are changed when a new item is added

Tags: c#

```
    public List<Player> playerList = new List<Player>();
    public List<Player> Player_A = new List<Player>();

    for (int i = 0; i < playerList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (playerList[i].Id == 1)
                {
                    playerList[i].hp = inputfiled.text;
                    Player_A(playerList[i]);
                break;
                }
        }
```

after adding playerlist [i] to list player_A. all items in player_A list have been changed to same, like playerlist [i] has just been added.
For example:

```
playerlist[0].hp = 100
add playerlist[0] -> playerList_A.
playerList_A[0].hp = 100

playerlist[1].hp = 50.
add playerlist[0] -> playerList_A.
playerList_A[0].hp = 50 and playerList_A[1].hp = 50;
```

As such, previous items will be valued when a new item is added.

Comment: Where and how are you adding items into `playerList`? And what is `Player`? Please provide a proper [mcve]

Comment: What is that you want to achieve with thi code? THe way the pseudo code you have shared is written seems like you are getting the cprrect behaviour

Comment: Also what is `Player_A(playerList[i]);` Does it compile?

Answer (score 0):

When add playlist[0] to player_A , You add referenced the address of that memory  in heap
Better you create new instance of items and then add to player_a

Comment: That is only true (assuming you actually mean it adds a reference to an object, you don't manipulate heap memory directly in C#) if `Player` is a reference type - which we cannot know without OP providing the code

Answer (score 0):

It is logical the item in the list is changing. This is because you have the line of code:

playerList[i].hp = inputfiled.text;

you are refering to the object in the playerList. It seems you want to create a new object and add this to the new list: Player_A

Change your code to:

```
  Player copiedPlayer = new Player();
  copiedPlayer.Id = playerList[i].Id;
  etc.
  copiedPlayer.hp = 100;
  Player_A.Add(copiedPlayer);
```

You can also make the Player implement IClonable and clone the object.

Comment: You are welcome. Please confirm by marknig the question as answered.